# auto add reaction to message attachment in channel

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

so i made a code that if a person sends an attachment ina certain channel it would react to it but I can't seem to make it work

Here's my code

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.attachments in message.channel.name == "memes-only":
    await asyncio.sleep(2)
    await message.add_reaction("")
    await message.add_reaction("")
    channel = message.channel
    await channel.send("i have reacted")
    await message.delete()
```

i have also tried it with **if message.attachments in message.channel.id == "860073616606625792":**

edit: my traceback says **TypeError: argument type of int is not iterable**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so you have this weird if statement

```
if message.attachments in message.channel.name == "memes-only":
```

the thing it is doing is first checking is message.attackments is in `message.channel.name == 'memes-only'` which is a boolean value
what you want to do is

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.channel.name == "memes-only":
        await asyncio.sleep(2)
        await message.add_reaction("")
        await message.add_reaction("")
        channel = message.channel
        await channel.send("i have reacted")
        await message.delete()
```

Comment: ohh okayy, but like how do you make it so that it only reacts to attachments?

Comment: i mean it does work but it reacts to every message that is sent in the channel

Comment: add a check to see if the message contains attachments, just like u did to see if the message was in  a particular channel